Create Outlook calendar event and invitation using Graph API
I'm trying to create a meeting invite in Outlook using the Graph API but it appears to be more difficult than anticipated.
I can create an event in somebody's calendar using POST /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/calendar/events, but that event appears only in that person's calendar, not in attendees' calendars - and there is no associated meeting invite (EventMessage) which can be sent.
I cannot create an EventMessage because it is not possible to POST /users/{id|userPrincipalName}/messages with an EventMessage (or an EventMessageRequest) in the body.
Can it really be that it is not possible to create a meeting invite using the Graph API?

Did you check the spam folders for invites, a lot of the time when this happens the invite is being marked as spam. If your creating a meeting then invites should always be sent. Also check the SentItems folder of the meeting organizer you should see the invite there.
